# How to manipulate responseBody in spring Interceptorsusing using Something like ClientHttpResponseInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am receiving a encrypted message for REST API and manipulating the encrypted RequestBody with below interceptor to decrypt it and passing.

Similar way how I can **re-encrypt the response body with another Interceptor like** **ClientHttpResponseInterceptor** ? but I don't see anything like `ClientHttpResponseInterceptor` really....

For request I am doing , what to do for Response?

```
public class EncryptingClientHttpRequestInterceptor
                implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, 
                    ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        //encrypt method define the encryption logic
        byte[] decryptedreqBody = decrypt(body);
        return execution.execute(request, decryptedreqBody);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Externally we don't want to encrypt the http response, because https is secured over SSL ie., https protocol will take care of encryption.